# Changing unstaking period

Tags: staking

I'm trying to change unstaking period 3 days to 5 seconds.

I edited `/eos/contract/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp` like below.

[image]

After that, I executed `eosio_build.sh`.

However, when I execute command:

```
cleos push action eosio refund '{"owner":"accountname"}' -p accountname
```

It is always failed like before!
[image]

So, I removed `build/ directory` and tried rebuilding eosio (using `eosio_build.sh`), but it shows same result.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Reckon you might need to start a fresh chain?

Comment: @JohnWilliamson You mean if I start a fresh chain, changes will be applied?

Comment: Worth a shot! ;)